# How do the Hirogen interact with the Borg?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

Both have similar properties.

They are predatory.

The Hirogen see every approach of prey to defend themselves as incentive.

The Borg see every species worth assimilating as prey.

The Borg can adapt, Hirogen never give up.

Comment: We see multiple Hirogen as *assimilated Borg*. Does that answer your question sufficiently?

Comment: The Borg most certainly do not see every species as worthy of assimilation, only those that can bring some useful aspect to the Collective. Notably they ignore the Kazon because they have no useful characteristics.

Comment: @Valorum where were Hirogen turned into drones?

Comment: Valorum, I'm a little bit surprised that nanoprobes work on the Hirogen. I remember a Voyager episode where a loaded hypo from the EMH doesn't put a Hirogen down.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hirogen

Comment: @Valorum If it was only useful aspects, why have they not assimilated ocampa for their psychic powers?

Comment: @Valorum Maybe, but it doesn't make sense that they were easily assimilated given their characteristics. And only over time the borg assimilated enough technology to assimilate stronger opponents. There is a narrative untold.

Comment: @Valorum is there anything considered canon which would indicate if the Borg assimilate (or attempt to assimilate) every single species that they encounter?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - There's plenty of evidence to suggest that they *sample* anything and everything that the find. There's also plenty of evidence that they don't assimilate species that they assess (after the initial 'assimilation profile' is created) to be unworthy of their attentions.

Comment: "The Borg see every species worth assimilating as prey" — no, they don't. As Locutus said, they only wish to improve quality of life. They don't kill or eat species; they make species part of the Borg. That's not a predator/prey relationship.

Comment: But to answer your question, how do the Hirogen interact with the Borg? *Very carefully.*

Comment: @PascalWidmann: Probably, assimilation does not quite work like an RPG with individual transferrable "skills".

Comment: @PaulD.Waite  - All signs point to the opposite. They likely approach them with a massive sense of their own superiority and are surprised when they get pulverised

Comment: @PascalWildman - That's probably worthy of its own question. Off the top of my head I would say it is probably because the Ocampa are extremely short-lived, have lived largely under the protection of a superior incorporeal being, that their planet is well inside Kazon territory, is well outside of Borg space and that their psychic abilities are (at least on first glance) relatively inferior as compared to, for example, the Vulcans.

Comment: @Valorum Funny that you mention the Vulcans out of all species. Because once Tuvok and Kes trained together, Kes was able to make Tuvok change shape https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jak5D31mxM

Answer (score 5):

The Hirogen and the Borg appear to have a relatively fraught relationship, with the Borg assimilating them as they catch them and the Hirogen largely being unaware of them as a potential threat.

We certainly know that Hirogen have been assimilated  and are used as drones ([I](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Hirogen#Borg_drone), [II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Hirogen#Borg_drone_rebel), [III](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Artifact_personnel#Hirogen_xB))  rather than just captured (for their [assimilation profile](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Assimilation_profile)) and then disposed of.

Note that the Hirogen are nomadic and don't have a recognised homeworld, so the fact that the Borg would make mincemeat of them doesn't seem to have filtered down to their collective conscience yet.

> **KARR:** *I've been studying Voyager's database looking for our next simulation. There are many to choose from. These people have a violent history. **I believe I've found a worthy prey. The Borg.** When World War Two is over, we will recreate a notorious battle known as Wolf 359.*
>
> <sub><sup>The Killing Game</sup></sub>

---

As an aside, the Borg most certainly do not see every *species* as worthy of assimilation. They will *sample* a species that they're unaware of, but they reserve species-wide assimilation for those races that bring them closer to perfection.

> **SEVEN:** *The Borg encountered a Kazon colony in the Gand Sector, grid six nine two zero.*
> **NEELIX:** *Were they assimilated?*
> **SEVEN:** *Their biological and technological distinctiveness was unremarkable. They were unworthy of assimilation.*
> **NEELIX:** *I didn't realise the Borg were so discriminating.*
> **SEVEN:** *Why assimilate a species that would detract from perfection?*

Answer (score -1):

Canonically there is no real answer however it is unlikely that Hirogen would actively hunt Borg simply because it would not even be a hunt most likely Hirogen would ignore Borg unless they tried to assimilate them in which case resistance would be attempted.

Answer (score -1):

The series canon (which is frankly all that matters) never indicates what happens between the Hirogen and The Borg.

For one thing, the Borg's space, while vast, is also finite, and doesn't encompass the entirety of the Delta QUadrant. Given the Hirogen's relatively "primitive" FTL technology and thus their inability to spread their "hunts" over the length of and breadth of the entire quadrant, it's unlikely that they encounter the Borg very often. Additionally, the Hirogen would more likely than not be killed in any such Borg encounters rather than submitting and there's no indication that the Borg would routinely reanimate their deceased opponents.

The series itself makes it clear that many advanced races never encounter The Borg or only consider them to be a minor threat. The Vaudaur are examples of this, as are The Voth. Neither group's evolution, nor technological progress, were shown to have been impaired by the Borg and in fact, they both carved out their vast empires within the Delta Quadrant. The Hirogen might find themselves in that august group.

Finally it likely never occurred to the writers to link the two races together. This is seen several times throughout the series, especially when it's never explained why the Krenim's time-alteration technology (The Year of Hell) did not attract the Borg. The Hirogen came into play well after Voyager left "Borg space" and so the needs of the narrative might not have encompassed stories that defined the two group's interactions.